# How to create dropdownbottom and checkbox in same line without having problem of printing their value

Tags: flutter

I have this flutter code but I dont know how to get their values when title == Fumatore..
I tried some solutions with chat gpt but when i create it dropdown and checkbox they are having same activation (for example if i create dropdown with yes and no strings with values true and false, my checkbox also getting automatically true or false)

```
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  late AttDataService _attDataService;
  late Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _dataFuture; // Change the type
  late List<TextEditingController> _controllers;
  late List<bool> _isCheckedList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _attDataService = AttDataService();
    _dataFuture = fetchDataDetails(); // Call a new function to get details
    _controllers = [];
    _isCheckedList = [];
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchDataDetails() async {
    try {
      final List<Attribute> attributes = await _attDataService.fetchData();
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> detailsList = [];

      for (Attribute attribute in attributes) {
        for (var nestedAttribute in attribute.attributes) {
          String nestedName = nestedAttribute['attribute']['name'];
          var value = nestedAttribute['value'];
          var lifesaver = nestedAttribute['lifesaver'];
          Map<String, dynamic> details = {
            'nestedName': nestedName,
            'value': value,
            'lifesaver': lifesaver,
          };
          detailsList.add(details);
          _controllers.add(TextEditingController(
              text: value != null ? value.toString() : ''));
          _isCheckedList.add(lifesaver ?? false);
        }
      }
      return detailsList;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    for (var controller in _controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Widget'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: _dataFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else {
            // Data loaded successfully
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> detailsList = snapshot.data ?? [];
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: detailsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map<String, dynamic> details = detailsList[index];
                String nestedName = details['nestedName'];
                var lifesaver = details['lifesaver'];
                return TextFormWithTitle(
                  title: nestedName,
                  hintText: 'Enter $nestedName',
                  controller: _controllers[index],
                  obscureText: false,
                  hasSOSIcon: true,
                  isChecked: _isCheckedList[index],
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isCheckedList[index] = newValue ?? false;
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextFormWithTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String hintText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obscureText;
  final bool hasSOSIcon;
  final bool isChecked;
  final void Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  const TextFormWithTitle({
    Key? key,
    required this.title, //here will go nested attribute name
    required this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
    required this.controller, // here will go fetched our value
    required this.hasSOSIcon,
    required this.isChecked, //here will go fetched lifesaver if true check box if not dont check
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: hintText,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                ),
                obscureText: obscureText,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
        if (hasSOSIcon)
          Column(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: isChecked,
                onChanged: onChanged,
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0), // Adjust spacing as needed
              Image.asset(
                'assets/page-1/images/ellipse-18.png',
                width: 54,
                height: 47,
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.